# How edit or add properties in inline task

Tags: msbuild

I need invoke msbuild task with properties, whats name can be calculated only in runtime. I try do it by this scripts

**Main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="14.0" DefaultTargets="Build">

  <UsingTask TaskName="GetVars" TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0.dll">        
    <ParameterGroup>
      <Result ParameterType="System.String" Output="true"/>
    </ParameterGroup>
    <Task>
      <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs">
        <![CDATA[
          this.Result = "AAA=123;BBB=456;";
        ]]>
      </Code>
    </Task>
  </UsingTask>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <Vars></Vars>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="Make">
    <GetVars>
      <Output TaskParameter="Result" PropertyName="Vars"/>
    </GetVars>

    <MSBuild Projects="Proj.xml" Targets="make" Properties="$(Vars)"/>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

**Proj.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" DefaultTargets="Build">
    <Target Name="Make">
        <Message Text="AAA = $(AAA)"/>
        <Message Text="BBB = $(BBB)"/>
    </Target>
</Project>
```

This script give this output:

```
AAA = 123;BBB=456;
BBB =
```

I expected this output:

```
AAA = 123;
BBB = 456;
```

Comment: Please provide a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so others can try just the relevant part of the code. Anyway, if I understand correctly what you want this is pretty standard msbuild and also covered in the documentation for inline tasks: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd723643.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396. In short: if you want an item instead of a property, output an array instead of a string, and use ItemName="Vars".

Comment: I change question for MVC. Later i look _items_ concept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the inline task to produce several items (the msbuild equivalent of an array or list in other languages), you should state it like that instead of using a property (which is a single key/value pair). This is covered in some of the Inline Task [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd723643.aspx?f=255&mspperror=-2147217396#Anchor_4) - however that uses full-blown ITaskItems whereas just using a String array will do. So:

- output a `System.String[]` from the inline task
- assign it to an Item instead of Property using `ItemName =`
- pass the Item to the MSbuild task (which is what it expects anyway), using `@()` notation

In code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="14.0" DefaultTargets="Make">

  <UsingTask TaskName="GetVars" TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0.dll">        
    <ParameterGroup>
      <Result ParameterType="System.String[]" Output="true"/>
    </ParameterGroup>
    <Task>
      <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs">
        <![CDATA[
          this.Result = new System.String[]{"AAA=123", "BBB=456"};
        ]]>
      </Code>
    </Task>
  </UsingTask>

  <Target Name="Make">
    <GetVars>
      <Output TaskParameter="Result" ItemName="Vars"/>
    </GetVars>
    <MSBuild Projects="$(MSBuildThisFile)" Targets="Show" Properties="@(Vars)"/>
  </Target>

  <Target Name="Show">
    <Message Text="AAA = $(AAA)"/>
    <Message Text="BBB = $(BBB)"/>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Output:

```
Show:
  AAA = 123
  BBB = 456
```